# Bokeh error when using periodic callback

Tags: python, bokeh

I've been messing with the periodic_callback and it keeps throwing an error. However, I really don't understand why? All the code works in isolation and as soon as I add in the update function using Bokeh server an error is thrown...

Some context:

I've attached the code below - the main function makes an API call to google analytics and pulls daily active users (time and number). This works correctly outside of the Bokeh function. This data is then fed into a dataframe and a few operations are carried out in order to put it in the right form for plotting. The Bokeh stream function is then used to just update the current column data source.

Unfortunately, when I run the function I get the following error:

```
Error thrown from periodic callback: AttributeError("'ColumnDataSource' object has no attribute 'keys'",)
```

I have no idea what this even means when I'm not trying to access a file or directory?

The function:

```
def update():

    t = main()
    DAU = pd.DataFrame(t['rows'], columns=['Date', 'Vol'])
    DAU['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(DAU['Date'])
    DAU['Vol'] = DAU.Vol.astype(int)

    new = ColumnDataSource(DAU)

source.stream(new)

source = ColumnDataSource({'Date': [], 'Vol': []})

p1 = figure(toolbar_location=None, x_axis_type='datetime')
p1.border_fill_color = 'black'
p1.background_fill_color = 'black'
p1.outline_line_color = None
p1.grid.grid_line_color = None

r1 = p1.line('Date', 'Vol', color="navy", line_width=4, source=source)

curdoc().add_periodic_callback(update, 50)

curdoc().add_root(p1)
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `stream` method [takes a dict as argument](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/data.html#streaming) and it's looking for the `dict`'s `keys()` method in your `ColumnDataSource` object hence the error.